# InView package not working in react native typescript mobile app

Tags: react-native

In my TypeScript React Native mobile app, I'm trying to detect elements appearing on the screen. I'm trying to use many packages such as [react-native-inview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-inview) and [react-native-component-inview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-component-inview) but they keep throwing `typescript typing` related errors. How can I resolve these errors or is there other ways or packages available which are typescript supported?

Error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-inview'. 'PATH/node_modules/react-native-inview/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-native-inview` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-native-inview';`
```

Note: The automatically specified type packages do not exist such as `npm i --save-dev @types/react-native-inview`.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you didn't add these packages correctly to your app. Have you tried pod install command in your ios folder? If it is not the case, I recommend refreshing your node modules in your app directory.

Comment: Hi, I'm testing my app on the Android Studio - Emulator. I ran these commands to install the packages: `npm i --save react-native-inview` and `npm i --save react-native-component-inview`. Which other packages should I be installing?